# overridePendingTransition not working on android 2.3.5

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

This code of mine is not working... I have checked all the links on this site and also tried animation listener but still its not working.

```
public class SplashScreenPage extends Activity implements Runnable{

Thread splash;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_page_layout);

    splash = new Thread(this);
    splash.start();
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        splash.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenPage.this,LoginPage.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();
     SplashScreenPage.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    super.onPause();

}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with your device's default settings.  Go to settings > display > animation > allow "all animations".  This will allow overridePendingTransition to work properly.

Comment: This is the real answer.

Comment: +1 for me. I changed the settings of my device and voila the animation is working now :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see is that you're using your animation in a different Thread of the main thread. That main thread is also known as the UI Thread. So, you need to get back to that UI Thread. This should work (I use overridePendingTransition(0, 0) to remove any animation, you can experiment with others:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        presentLogo();
    }

    /** Called to present the Splash image for an amount of time */
    private void presentLogo() {
        final SplashActivity splashActivity = this;
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (splashActivity) {
                        try {
                            sleep(Constants.SPLASH_PRESENTATION_DURATION);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        } finally {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    finish();
                                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

                                    // After splash, go to the new activity
                                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                                    intent.setClass(splashActivity, LoginActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                         });
                     }
                 }
             }
         }.start();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenPage.this,LoginPage.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply.. but how do I add the animation to it

Comment: I think you had it right, you just needed to `finish` before you started your new `Intent`.

Comment: I replaced my code with your code and called finish before starting the new activity. I also put the new overpanding code in onpause. but still no luck

Comment: Try just moving finish and put on pause back. Like I said before, I think you had it right.

Comment: Okay, sorry. One other change. See edited post. `overridePendingTransition` needs to go directly after `finish` then your `Intent`. Should work!

Comment: Try loosing the android in: android.R.anim.slide_in_left and android.R.anim.slide_in_right

Comment: ok here is my final code I have tired-  finish();
  SplashScreenPage.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
  Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenPage.this,LoginPage.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 and it does not work

Comment: Get rid of the `android`. Make it like this: `finish(); SplashScreenPage.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right); Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenPage.this,LoginPage.class); startActivity(intent);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13793/discussion-between-raj-and-blaineomega)